# How to specify browser binary in selenium remote webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to use Firefox portable for my tests in python. In plain webdriver it works, but i was wondering how to do it in remote webdriver.
All i could find is how to pass firefox profile, but how to specify to webdriver which binary to use?

Answer (score 3):

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary('path/to/binary');
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary);
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Very hacky, but you could modify the Webdriver Firefox plugin to point to your binary.